# StylesProvider vs StyledEngineProvider in Material UI v5

Tags: material-ui

I'm attempting to migrate from Material-UI v4 to v5 (currently in beta), but I'm not sure if I replace `StylesProvider` with `StyledEngineProvider`. There is no mention of it (see https://next.material-ui.com/guides/migration-v4/). The migration guide only mentions that `StylesProvider` should be imported directly from `@material-ui/styles` (instead of `@material-ui/core/styles`). It also mentions using `StyledEngineProvider` with the `injectFirst` option to take care of the css ordering. However, that is what `StylesProvider` does so I'm confused if I need to use `StylesProvider` or `StyledEngineProvider`.

Do I use `StyledEngineProvider` instead of `StylesProvider`? Or does it not matter because they both do the same thing? Or do I use `StylesProvider` if I am still using JSS and only use `StyledEngineProvider` if I no longer use JSS and only use Emotion? Any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: Using this github issue as a reference: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/24109
 Trying to solve the same issue and it seems this is on the right track so far.

Answer (score 20):

Yep, I agree with those missing details among the two. After navigating over the repo, the difference is that `StyledEngineProvider` allows you to customize the current instance of `StylesProvider` used by MUI so by injecting Emotion first, JSS continues to work as before (`<StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>`).

It does matter which one you use, `StylesProvider` breaks the theme since you are creating your own provider without MUI's internal configuration, instead, `StyledEngineProvider` is only passing down a property to MUI's internal `StylesProvider`.

These APIs are offered as backward compatibility with V4, so it only affects JSS users. Currently, you can use both, but consider migrating your JSS styling to Emotion.

As in version 5.0.5, this should let you continue working with JSS:

```js
import {
   ThemeProvider,
   StyledEngineProvider,
   CssBaseline,
} from '@mui/material';
import {
   createTheme
   responsiveFontSizes,
} from '@mui/material/styles';
// import { StylesProvider } from '@mui/styles'; //breaks MUI theme!

const muiTheme = responsiveFontSizes(createTheme({/* your custom theme */}));

export const withJssAndCustomTheme = Component => props=>{
return (
         <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
            <ThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>
               <CssBaseline/>
               <Component
                  {...props}
               />
            </ThemeProvider>
         </StyledEngineProvider>
      );
};

// withJssAndCustomTheme(App) // wrap your root component
```

Comment: i have migrated my styles from jss. but when i delete `StyledEngineProvider `, the app break... why does not work without it, i'm not using JSS anymore.

Comment: the StyledEngineProvider could be a problem if you are using Next.js, you can use createCache({ key: 'css', prepend: true }) to prepend to the top.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was migrating from v4 to v5 and run `npx @mui/codemod v5.0.0/preset-safe` which used `@mui/styles` instead of `@mui/material` when importing `ThemeProvider` and `StyledEngineProvider`

Comment: I was able to swap out `StylesProvider` with `StyledEngineProvider` without making any other code changes (I'm using styled-components) and remove the `@mui/styles` package completely.